# Angular js binding "<" give undefined inside controller

Tags: angularjs

I have "invite-friends-code" component which get data through binding "<". The problem is, it is pass correctly and show in the view directly, but when i trying to munipulate with it inside "invite-friends-code" controller it gives me "undefined"

component

```
   const inviteFriendsCodeComponent = {
    bindings: {
        leagueCode: '<'
    },
    templateUrl: '/js/common/invite-friends-code/invite-friends-code.html'+assetsVersion,
    controller: 'InviteFriendsCodeController'
 }
```

binding using inside other component view:

```
 <invite-friends-code league-code="$ctrl.leagueData.code"></invite-friends-code>
```

controller:

```
ctrl.$onInit = () => {
 console.log(ctrl.leagueCode) // gives me undefined here 
}
```

Comment: Please show your controller and component code.

Comment: You code is limited so difficult to find solution. Add more code

Comment: updated code...

Comment: Did you bind `this` to `ctrl` ?

Comment: yes, "const ctrl = this";

Comment: I think you need to show us more code to fully understand your issue

Answer (score 2):

Your bindings are not initialized yet!

You can use `$onInit` function.

```
app.component('yourComponent', {
  bindings: {
    leagueCode: '<'
  },
  controller: function() {
    var ctrl = this;

    this.$onInit = function() {
       console.log(this.leagueCode)
    });
  }
}
```

[Official doc](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/component)

Comment: How do you his bindings are not initialized? did you see the whole code?

Comment: @VicJordan this is a common error I often see about AngularJS component